# How to synchronize sidewaystable with the odd/even page?

Tags: floats, double-sided, rotating

I have two tables, T1 and T2. I want these to appear in two pages as if the head-side of the table remains at the binding side of the book. Like this

> |||||>|<|||||
>
> |||||>|<|||||
>
> |||||>|<|||||

I have used,

```
\begin{sidewaystable} 
\begin{center}
\caption{My caption} 
\begin{tabular}{ ... ...}
```

This indeed rotates the tables, but the top-side of the tables go to the edge-side of the page.

Any idea how to fix it? I would prefer to use rotate and tell to move X degree manually.

Comment: Do you really want that your readers have to turn the book twice in order to read the two tables?

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? When I create a minimal example using your setup with the `book` document class in `twoside` mode, `sidewaystable` puts the `tabular` header facing the gutter (or binding side) and not the edge. That is, the header is on the left when the page is [recto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recto_and_verso) and on the right when the page is [verso](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recto_and_verso).

Comment: @Werner, 

I am using, \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

Yes, I am trying achieve what you have just explained.

Comment: So, as mentioned, when I create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), even using `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}` (which is typeset in `twoside` mode by default) the alignment is as you requested (headers toward the gutters). So, you must be doing something else. Please [edit your post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/39596/edit) and provide an MWE that duplicates the unwanted behaviour your specify. [Here](http://pastebin.com/0WdqAyiu) is a start to see where I'm coming from.

Comment: Seconding Werner here. I am using `sidewaystable` in the way you describe, and haven't observed your problems.

Answer (score 2):

The `dpfloat` package may help.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{dpfloat}
\title{Example}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

text\clearpage
more text

\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{leftfullpage}
    Left part of float
\end{leftfullpage}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{fullpage}
    Right part of float
\end{fullpage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mention that the two `sidewaystable`s are currently both aligned at the top of their respective, consecutive pages. I interpret your question as asking how to get the first page to be bottom-aligned (while keeping the second table top-aligned).

The easiest way I know of accomplishing this is to issue the place the first of the two sideways-tables in a local group (say, with `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` statements) and to issue the follwing commands after the `\begingroup` command but before the `\begin{sidewaystable}` statement:

```
\makeatletter
\setlength\@fptop{0pt plus 1fill}
\setlength\@fpbot{0pt}
\makeatother
```

These commands serve to bottom-align the first of the two tables. To top-align the second table, you could use the same approach while exchanging the arguments of the two `\setlength` statements.